# Select a specific property from array of objects angular

Tags: jquery, arrays, angularjs, linq

I have a array of objects, for e.g. like one below.

```
[{ "foo" : "a", "bar" : "x", baz: 1},
{ "foo" : "b", "bar" : "y", baz: 2},
{ "foo" : "c", "bar" : "z", baz: 3}]
```

Now I want to select only foo property from this array to another array like

```
["a","b","c"]
```

I can do this using looping and adding each property to another array as

```
var fooArray =[];
angular.forEach(arrayName, function (value, key) {
    fooArray.push(value.foo);               
});
```

But is is possible just as we do in c# linq select statement without us looping into the array like

```
var fooArray = arrayName.Select(m => m.foo) // c# way
```

Is there any elegant way without us looping?

Comment: Using ECMAScript 2015: `arrayName.map(m => m.foo)`

Comment: @Vohuman : How to mix ECMAScipt with angular, i have not used this before?

Comment: @Chaitanya Gadkari: ECMAScript is the specification underlying JavaScript. It only works with supported browsers (or if you have a converter). At that point it's just a language feature, which works with angular because angular is just a framework that runs in the language.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `map` function like below. It is modern browser's script I mean it will perfectly work in `IE8+` versions. It will not work in `IE8` older versions.

As per doc

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a
>   provided function on every element in this array.

**AND**

> Calls a defined callback function on each element of an array, and
>   returns an array that contains the results.

```
var result = arrayName.map(function(a) {return a.foo;});
```

Comment: FYI IE8 is not a "modern browser" and doesn't support the method.

Comment: @Vohuman thanks for your information sir, That's why I mentioned `IE8+` browsers.

Answer (score 0):

`var result = arrayName.map(o=>o.foo)`

Comment: Why would you change the function from the accepted answer to an arrow function, but leave the `var` alone? When adding late answers, please try to be more thorough.